# yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: cinghie\articles\Articles::0

Tags: yii2

Good day, 
tried to install this extension
https://github.com/cinghie/yii2-articles

I get such an error, how can I fix it?

```
yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: cinghie\articles\Articles::0 in** /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(546): yii\base\Component->__set('0', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(cinghie\articles\Articles), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(158): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\Module->__construct('articles', Object(yii\web\Application), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(384): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('cinghie\\article...', Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('cinghie\\article...', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(427): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(586): yii\base\Module->getModule('articles')
#9 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(522): yii\base\Module->createController('categories')
#10 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('articles/catego...', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/basic/web/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

Perhaps the reason is that according to the instructions, you need to override `PREFIX_` with a table prefix. I did it like this:

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `auth_assignment` (` item_name`, `user_id`,` created_at`) VALUES
('admin', '1', 1451514052);
```

after the SQL query produces the following

MySQL response:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`ubuntu`.`auth_assignment`, CONSTRAINT `auth_assignment_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`item_name`) REFERENCES `auth_item` (`name`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**Update**

The SQL query was executed, the admin id = 1 entry was added, but the error remains the same:

> Setting unknown property: cinghie \ Articles \ Articles :: 0

Maybe because 3 migrations from 7 failed:

[output from console](https://pastebin.com/LwbBWxNQ)

Comment: I fixed formatting BUT you must ask your question in English.

Answer (score 0):

Wha looks like you havent added the `admin` role before assigning the role to your user, make sure you have the `admin` role added in your `auth_item` table as the foreign key constraint error is referring to, there should be an entry like below

```
+-------+------+-------------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
| name  | type | description | rule_name | data | created_at | updated_at |
+-------+------+-------------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
| admin |    1 | NULL        | NULL      | NULL | 1525039496 | 1525039496 |
+-------+------+-------------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

otherwise, run the following query

```
INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`) VALUES
('admin', 1);
```

Now run the query that is required by the extension and it will work fine.

```
INSERT INTO `auth_assignment` (` item_name`, `user_id`,` created_at`) VALUES
('admin', '1', 1451514052);
```

**Update**

The migration failed because you don't have a user with `id = 1` in the `user` table, see the error that is being raised for the foreign key.

> Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`ubuntu`.`article_items`, CONSTRAINT `fk_article_items_user_id`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

and the sql executed has the id `1` as `user_id` that is being inserted so you should make sure you have the user with same `id`

Comment: The SQL query was executed, the admin id = 1 entry was added, but the error is still the same:

setting unknown property: cinghie \ articles \ Articles :: 0

perhaps because 3 of 7 migrations did not pass
output from the console: https://pastebin.com/LwbBWxNQ

Comment: The migration failed because you dont have a `id` in `user` table with the value `1` see the error that is being raised for the foreign key @OlegKlochkov

Comment: what do you mean by `admin=1 ` was inserted , can you show you table data for `auth_assignment` `auth_item` and `user` @OlegKlochkov

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Vm6lLQbtDNgK1A    http://joxi.ru/VrwNXqQUOWlv8A    http://joxi.ru/bmonLWOTxGpokr

Comment: @OlegKlochkov you have the admin user with the id 57 whereas you have associated the role of the admin with the user id 1 which is no where , you should know what you are doing, you should either drop all users from the user table using truncate option in phpmyadmin or either replaced the id in the migration `m170616_185620_insert_article_data_demo` and all others where ever the user_id is being inserted ,you should learn how to integrate extensions by following their documentation carefully